# Is a phrase 'your happy being' correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, adjectives, phrasal-verbs

My friend asked me to the beach with this sentence:

> The beach is waiting for your happy being.

Is the sentence he used correct?

Comment: It's grammatically fine (_being_ is a noun, apart from being a participle), but it's not very idiomatic. “Your happy presence” would be a bit more natural, but still a bit odd.

Comment: It's unusual to modify a pronoun with an adjective, whether or not one adds a dummy head noun (_your presence = your being = you_) to justify it. I would say it's either a loan translation of a local term or -- especially if it happened in the US --  gratuitous overformality.

Comment: @Janus 'Being' is a deverbal noun as well as a gerund. I'm not sure which makes less sense here.

Comment: @John, I read the invitation as deliberately (but not entirely successfully) using a very formal formula for humorous effect; the formula being that of “(we eagerly await) your kind/speedy/whatever reply” or “(I remain) your faithful servant”, etc.

Comment: @Janus, Right. Gratuitous overformality. Possibly due to non-native speaker, whence the loan translation option.

Comment: @Janus: Anything's possible, but I read it as an interaction between two non-native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically correct.  If the sentence is supposed to be an invitation, the invitation is missing.  A colloquial equivalant might be:

*Let's go to the beach and have a good time.*